# Excel entering the date time into a cell when another cell has a value entered into it

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am trying to create a column that acts as a unique key value for each row, by adding the Now() value when the last column has had its data entered into it. I have created a sub that checks the range of cells for one to be selected and have a value in it and if it is, add the Now() value to another column to act as a unique identifier for that row. This is the code that i have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As range)

    'Check to see if the click/selected cell is in column H
    If Not Intersect(Target, range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then

        'Make sure just one cell is selected and it isnt empty
        If Target.Cells.Value <> "" And Target.Row > 7 And Target.Row <= 20 Then

            'Update the "KeyA" value
            range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Now()
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Unfortunately this only adds the Now() value to the key column if the selected cell already has a value in it so if I click the empty cell and then add the value, it does not add Now() to the key column. How do I make the sub add the Now() value once an entry has been added to the selected cell with out having to re-select the cell after I have added a value to it?

Comment: Use `Worksheet_Change` event instead of `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.  Change will fire when the value in the target cell is amended, whereas SelectionChange fires when you select a different cell.

Comment: if you write that in an answer I will mark it right and upvote

Comment: I'm slightly confused about what you are asking. Is the value in column H already there when the `Now()` value is added or do you want it updated after changing the value? If after, try the Change event: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)`

Comment: I wanted it to update after changing the value, im using that column as a hidden key column so that when my continuous sub that copies the data from one sheet to another checks if that key value exists, if it already does  it will not be duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Worksheet_Change` event instead of `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.

`Change` will fire when the value in the target cell is amended, whereas `SelectionChange` fires when you select a different cell.